# Movie from the last couple of decades that looks 80s but isn't; robot with black reflective faceplate

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was a rather figurative, almost arthouse piece if I remember correctly. Not actually an 80s sci fi movie, but looked like one in camerawork and production design.

Saw it at a friend's house five-plus years ago. Featured a tall robot (clearly person in suit) wearing as I recall red or orange, looked a bit like biking leathers. Robot wore a helmet with a black reflective faceplate. I seem to recall images of it standing in an almost transporter-pad-like room of tiled floor and ceiling. Lots of black, red and orange in the production design.

My memory is hazy but the 80s-style-movie-that-isn't-80s should narrow it down.

Am I misremembering - was this an experimental short, or something?

Comment: A 1980s movie with black-clad androids with featureless reflective black masks sounds a lot like [*The Black Hole*](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0078869), which even uses a lot of [warm colours](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/the-black-hole/images/1/1e/Humanoid_Promo_04.jpg) in its palette.  But I can't recall a specific scene like you describe.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suspect that you're thinking of a man in red bike leathers and a black reflective helmet in a room that feels very 80s chic. He's not a robot.

Here is the image you're likely recalling:

[image: Beyond]

This is from the 2010 film [*Beyond the Black Rainbow*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1534085/). It is very inspired by the 80s films of David Cronenberg and this character - he's one of the main characters - appears in this outfit (and room) several times.

Here is another image:

[image: Beyond 2]